# fopen fread and fwrite trouble

Tags: php, fwrite, fread

I am trying to have a user write something in the text box. Then the text is written ON A NEW LINE in a file called "list.txt". Then I want the whole file to be read on the website. That way it will be like a chat room or something. The trouble is, right now it is telling me "Unable to open file." I have checked and the file's permissions and every type of user has full access. List.txt is also in the same directory as the php file. Also, when it was able to open the file, it would not write it on a new line. I know that this can be done using "\n" or PHP.EOL but neither of them seemed to work and sometimes they would stop the site from running all in itself. Please help me figure out what is going on, thanks.

```
<html>

<p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
<input name="text" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="send" method="post">
</p>

<p>
<?php


$file = fopen("list.txt") or die ("Unable to open file!");
$text = $_POST['text'];//where the hell do you put the new line indicator: "\n"//

fwrite($file, $text) or die ("Cannot write!");


$print = fread($file,filesize("list.txt", "a+"));
fclose($file);
echo $print;


?>


</p>


<?php //figure out how to make this a button that clears the file
/*
$fp = fopen("list.txt", "r+");
// clear content to 0 bits
ftruncate($fp, 0);
//close file
fclose($fp);*/
?>


</html>
```

Comment: why dont you use file_put_contents

Comment: Looks like you are using an access modifier in the `filesize()` function.  You only need one argument there, the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_put_contents`...

```
   $file = 'list.txt';
    $content =  $_POST['text']."\n";
    // Write the contents to the file, 
    // using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
    file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

As per the documentation

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()
>   successively to write data to a file.
>
> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the
>   existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks. I still have the problem that since i use $_POST as the contents, how do I make sure it writes to a new line?

Comment: That's what i have been trying. It seems that it still writes it on the same line. both in the file and on the site when it is read back

Comment: I think it added a space between each string but not a newline

Comment: Thats not possible...I ran this code and tested.. It adds a new line every time php file is callled... What  is your issue

Comment: Here is what happens:

Comment: If I type "This" *enter* "is" *enter* "a" *enter * "test": the file will read "Thisisatest" and the website will read "This is a test"

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the html. Is it possible that the size of the html area is not big enough to fit multiple lines?

Comment: UPDATE: I used "\r\n" and it is now using new lines in the file. However, it is still not writing new lines on the site.

Comment: I think i need to use something besides just file_get_contents to read it back including line breaks

Comment: I fixed it. I used $print = nl2br(file_get-contents(blah blah blah));

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem that your file will be locked for the time php write the content.

If you want to write at the same time, then you have a short time no access to your file. Thats the big problem of file based solutions. Database engines are made for that.